# Static files do not work in django-admin after adding Https - Django

Tags: django, server

After adding the SSL certificate, my static files do not work only in django-admin. Other files on the entire website work very well.
How can I fix this situation (preferably without brutal copying of django-admin static files to my application)?

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls', namespace='app')),
    path('media/<path>/', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    path('static/<path>/', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static/') 

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/media')
```

**app** (/etc/nginx/sites-available/app) After making changes to this file, they django-admin static file stopped working.

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/app/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    #listen 80;

    # add here the ip address of your server
    # or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ebluedesign.online;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ebluedesign.online/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ebluedesign.online/privkey.pem;


    server_name 101.170.18.112;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/app/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/app/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/app/app/static/;
    }

    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ebluedesign.online;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You should not have any static/ and media/ urls in your url patterns. The django static server isn't supposed to be used in production. That's why you have nginx with the location /static/ and location /media/ pointing to the `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` directories. Also you should `collectstatic` so that all your admin files are copied to your `STATIC_ROOT` directory (which preferably, should be at a higher level than your project, i.e. outside your git repo if you're using git).

Comment: I have one question, so why is it writing in the documentation to add a static folder to the application? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: That’s for `collectstatic`. It needs to know where all your static files are. It will collect all the files and copy them in your STATIC_ROOT. Then when using {% static %} in your templates it will construct the correct URL with respect to STATIC_ROOT. And finally you configure your web server to match the STATIC_URL (I.e all paths starting with E.g. /static/) with STATIC_ROOT (I.e all paths inside the root).

Comment: And for development Django just serves the files directly from within the various static directories you defined (no STATIC_ROOT needed)